# ffmpeg (No Transcoding) audio

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, music, apple

How to create still image with sound video with ffmpeg with no transcoding audio so that my audio would be left untouched, so there is no loss in quality. I tried with a lot of parameters and couldnt't find one i've tried

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c copy output.mkv

but audio does not sound the same when downloading it from a website and playing it. can someone help me? some examples of no transcoding audio parameters?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `-c copy` is used for copying the audio and video "as is", without transcoding (assuming there is no error message, the video codec is going to be MJPEG codec, and the audio codec is going to be MP3 codec). Play `audio.mp3` and `output.mkv` using the same Player software. They should sound the same. (the MP3 file is probably after transcoding, and not the original website codec). Note that the Bot is correct - please add enough details to identify an adequate answer...

Comment: thats what i mean i dont want the mp3 or any other audio file to transcode. i want it to sound when you download it raw